# Can I use 14/2 wire on a light fixture that only has 2 wires coming from it?

Tags: electrical

I have an old light fixture that I took apart and restored and got it looking nice because it looked nice. It only has 2 wires coming from it, but the wire I have has 3 wires coming from it romex 14/2. Should I just cut the neutral or just wire it on the ground side?

Comment: it is going to need 2 wires, hot and neutral

Comment: So should I use the white and black or the black and copper?

Comment: If you don’t know the difference between hot neutral and ground, I would caution against any DIY electrics.

Comment: I do know the difference I was simply asking which to use?

Comment: I’ve installed new breakers, outlets and a few little projects like that. Nothing major but enough to get me by.

Comment: My original comment I meant to say white not black I didn’t realize I did that

Comment: You always use the white and black.  The ground is there just for your safety and should not be used as part of the power circuit to conduct power.  White(neutral) should never be connected to ground, away from the main panel(only the main panel).

Comment: What kind of light fixture? Is this a desk lamp that plugs in, or a ceiling/wall light that is hard wired? A picture would help us help you. TBH, "Should I just cut the neutral or just wire it on the ground side?" really makes it sound like you don't know what you're doing... You should _never_ "just cut the neutral", or you won't have a completed circuit and _never_ wire the ground into the circuit - ground is there for safety _only_ - its job is to carry power in a fault condition to keep it from going through you.

Comment: Joe, no-one here is trying to be rude, but the fact that you're asking questions like "Should I just cut the neutral or just wire it on the ground side?" and "So should I use the white and black or the black and copper" means that you *don't* know the difference between neutral and ground. And the difference referred to is not "one is white and the other is bare copper", it's their *functional* difference in mains wiring. Getting this kind of stuff wrong is the kind of thing which kills you and/or burns your house down sooner or later.

Comment: Put the light fixture away, go to your local library, check out a book or two on basic home wiring, and read them cover to cover a few times. People (and not always the people who made the mistake) do get hurt or killed when this stuff is done wrong. It's not hard to do right, but you have to learn to do it right, as it's also easy to get things wrong. If the book your library has is old, there may be some incorrect information about a few things that have been updated (such as how switch loops are done in 2022 .vs. in 2008) but the vast majority of the information will be correct.

Comment: Not to pile on, but it’s worth noting that you can screw stuff up (ie, cut the neutral and complete the circuit with ground) and it’ll **look** like things work. Until somebody gets zapped on the faucet or the house burns down, that is. We all had to learn this at one time — we weren’t born with it.

Comment: Anytime you ask "should I cut a wire" the answer is "definitely not". We see many junction boxes where a wire is needed or would be really useful, but the previous nitwit cut it for no good reason. Wires which are to be unused should be capped off and pushed into the back of the box.